# How to add view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm making a simple mvc application using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/486161/Creating-a-simple-application-using-MVC?msg=4825882#xx4825882xx).

I'm having problem when I'm trying to add view named **UserAdd**

In my case add view window does not appear in which we select view engine, model class and scaffold template.

What I'm doing is:

1. right click on models folder
2. then add then new item
3. then select mvc4 view page (razor)
4. name it UserAdd
5. click add button

When I click add button it opens the UserAdd.cshtml page directly.

My question is:

How to open that add view window?

Comment: The context menu is, well, *contextual*. The Models folder is not meant for views, so you don't get the add view option. Use the Views folder and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try going to controller, right click on Action name `UserAdd()` and select Add View..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you adding your view you add a right template and you entered a correct model class and data context class.